# Certificates not working optimally with NGINX

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, tls

I have a test NGINX server that behaves strange with certificates. I have compiled NGINX 1.9.1 and custom openssl-1.0.2a on an Ubuntu 14.04-server.

```
$ nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.9.1
built by gcc 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2a 19 Mar 2015
TLS SNI support enabled
```

NGINX compilation:

```
sudo ./configure --prefix=/etc/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --with-http_ssl_module --with-openssl=/usr/src/openssl-1.0.2a --with-http_realip_module --with-http_stub_status_module --without-http_browser_module --without-http_geo_module --without-http_limit_req_module --without-http_limit_conn_module --without-http_memcached_module --without-http_referer_module --without-http_scgi_module --without-http_split_clients_module --without-http_ssi_module --without-http_userid_module --without-http_uwsgi_module
```

OpenSSL compilation

```
sudo ./config --prefix=/usr
```

I have set up the server and copied the config files from the production server. I am testing with two sites, one subdomain and one domain. This is the SSL-details for both sites

```
ssl_ciphers 'AES128+EECDH:AES128+EDH:!aNULL';
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
ssl_verify_depth 3;
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparams.pem;
```

My main question is why does not Tls 1.2 work on any of the sites. I get the following test on SSL Labs:

```
TLS 1.2 No
TLS 1.1 No
TLS 1.0 Yes
SSL 3   No
SSL 2   No
```

I have checked that the server have the TLS 1.2 ciphers.

```
$ openssl ciphers -v | grep 'TLSv1.2'
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
DH-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
DH-RSA-AES256-SHA256    TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
DH-DSS-AES256-SHA256    TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384  TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
AES256-GCM-SHA384       TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
AES256-SHA256           TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
DH-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
DH-RSA-AES128-SHA256    TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
DH-DSS-AES128-SHA256    TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA256  TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
AES128-GCM-SHA256       TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
AES128-SHA256           TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
```

Production uses and older NGINX and Openssl 1.0.1 and it works there. I have also a test server with NGINX 1.7.1 and OpenSSL 1.0.1f with the same problems with TLS 1.2.

So what am I doing wrong? I have researched it for a while, but not gotten it to work.

Comment: AES128+EECDH:AES128+EDH neither of these are in you tls1.2 cipher lists.

Comment: Sorry. Late answer as I forgot this over the summer. I forgot to add that I have tried different ssl ciphers, but with same result. I tried the list I got from Mozilla's security generator: https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/. There are ciphers from the list on the server in that one.